# When function returns result and when function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I see a lot that function returns NOT the result but the function. 
The example below shows that function **getWindow** returns function. Why it can't just return variable "win"? When I return result and when function?
Thank you.

```
var A = function(){};
A.prototype=
{
   getWindow : function()
   {
        var win = new B.window();
        return (
                this.getWindow = function()
                {
                    return win;
                })();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is equivalent to your code but is easier to understand:

```
A.prototype = {
    getWindow: function() {

        var win = new B.window();

        this.getWindow = function() {
            return win;
        };

        return win;

    }
}
```

Usage:

First, create an A instance:

```
var a = new A();
```

Then, call `getWindow` on that instance:

```
a.getWindow();
```

Here, the `getWindow` method of `A.prototype` is called. As you can see in my code above, `A.prototype.getWindow` will create a `new B.window()` and **return it**, however in between, it will also create a `getWindow` method **on the instance object** itself.

Now, if you call `getWindow` again:

```
a.getWindow();
```

`A.prototype.getWindow` **is no longer called** because the instance object itself has a `getWindow` method. This method returns the same "win" object that was returned when the `getWindow` method was called for the first time.

---

Your pattern allows for multiple `A` instances to use the same `A.prototype.getWindow` method to instantiate their own "win" objects. Consider this:

```
var a1 = new A,
    a2 = new A,
    a3 = new A;

a1.getWindow(); // creates window W1 and returns it
a2.getWindow(); // creates window W2 and returns it

a1.getWindow(); // returns window W1
a2.getWindow(); // returns window W2

a3.getWindow(); // creates window W3 and returns it

a1.getWindow(); // returns window W1
a2.getWindow(); // returns window W2
a3.getWindow(); // returns window W3
```

This is quite a useful pattern `:)`

---

**Update:**

This is your code:

```
return (this.getWindow = function() {
    return win;
})();
```

First, let's take a look at the expression inside the parens:

```
this.getWindow = function() { return win; }
```

As you can see, it's an assignment expression. An anonymous function object is assigned to the `getWindow` property of the object referenced by `this` (the instance object).

Note that this function returns the `win` object.

**The result of this assignment expression is the function object itself!** This means that the value inside the parens is the function object.

Now, let's take a look at the whole picture:

```
return ( the_function_object )();
```

We can remove the parens since we don't need them anymore:

```
return the_function_object();
```

As you can see, the function object is called, and **then** the return value of that function is returned.

As mentioned above, the function returns `win`. Therefore, the code resolves to this:

```
return win;
```

So what your code does is:

FIRST, it assigns `function() { return win; }` to `this.getWindow`.

SECOND, it returns the result of calling that function which is `win`.

My code produces the same result but is easier to understand:

```
this.getWindow = function() {
    return win;
};

return win;
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, a 'direct' function on type A overwrites the previous prototype function with the same name?

Comment: @pimvdb No - a `getWindow` method is added to the instance object itself (which is `a` in the code above). The `A.prototype.getWindow` method is not modified. However, `a.getWindow` now **shadows** the `A.prototype.getWindow` method, so that this prototype method becomes unaccessible to the instance object `a`.

Comment: why I need '()' in the end of the 'return'?

Comment: 'win' was declared as LOCAL variable. Shouldn't it to be destroyed once it's returned from the PROTOTYPE getWindow and thus returning from the INSTANCE getWindow should return undefined, isn't it?

Comment: @theateist No, the `win` variable will survive the first `getWindow` call - [because of closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/). In JavaScript, if a variable is used by an inner function, it will not be destroyed as long as the inner function exists. In this case, the inner function is assigned to `this.getWindow` as a permanent property - this means that the inner function will never die. And since the inner function is using the `win` variable, it (the variable) will also never die.